# Drop down in boot strap isn't working - Showing popper.js required in console

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

[image]I am trying to learn some bootstrap and while creating a Drop down, I see a Popper.js is required in the console,

Here is the HTML script,

```
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Select the Database</button>

         <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
         </div>

        </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you read the error, `dropdown.js` has a dependency which is Popper.js. Simply include the script on your project

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the console error, Bootstrap's dropdowns require Popper.js.

So add this in the `head` and it will work just fine

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>`

Also, add jQuery if not added already

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`